# Manage a collection in a list and combobox based on the StackPanel size - WPF

Tags: wpf, resize, stackpanel

I have a StackPanel contains an ItemControl that binds to and shows a list of buttons. I want to support a scenario in which upon resizing the StackPanel, the remaining buttons will be organized inside a Combobox.

[Resizing Stack Panel - Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jskkx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using and templating a ToolBar:

```
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Content="Button1"/>
        <Button Content="Button2"/>
        <Button Content="Button3"/>
        <Button Content="Button4"/>
        <Button Content="Button5"/>
    </ToolBar>
```

Note that based on [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/423b2efb-6f06-4bb1-8a0d-cc984ea73ada/toolbar-overflow-panel-with-single-item-in-a-row?forum=wpf), you need to change the *WrapWidth="200"* part of [the Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970772(v=vs.110).aspx) to a small number. Of course, it might not help you if the items have different widths. However, in that case, setting the Margin of them might help.

Comment: Thanks! It seems ToolBar is the only one with OverFlow mechanism.

Comment: You 're welcome. please consider [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)